# Youtube v3 API mediaBodyRequired

Tags: c#, youtube-api

The issue is:

```
{
   "error":{
      "errors":[
     {
        "domain":"youtube.video",
        "reason":"mediaBodyRequired",
        "message":"Bad Request",
        "locationType":"other",
        "location":"body"
     }
      ],
      "code":400,
      "message":"Bad Request"
   }
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
    private void CreateUploadRequest(SynchronisedAsset asset)
    {
        var endPoint = api.ApiUrl + "/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet"; // read for the different ways to interact with videos https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/#Videos
        var maxSize = 68719476736; // 64 gig

        try
        {
            var location = CompanyProvider.GetUploadLocation(this.baseUploadDirectory, companyId, FileType.Asset);
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(location, asset.FileName);
            var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            if (maxSize > fileBytes.Length && (asset.MimeType.ToLower().StartsWith("video/") || asset.MimeType.ToLower().Equals("application/octet-stream")))
            {
                var json = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{ \"snippet\": { \"title\": \"" + asset.FileName + "\", \"description\": \"This is a description of my video\" } }");

                var request = WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
                request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Bearer {0}", api.Tokens.AccessToken);
                request.ContentLength = json.Length;
                request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
                request.Headers["X-Upload-Content-Length"] = fileBytes.Length.ToString();
                request.Headers["X-Upload-Content-Type"] = asset.MimeType;
                request.Method = "POST";

                using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(json, 0, (int)json.Length);
                }

                var response = request.GetResponse();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            eventLog.WriteEntry("Error uploading to youtube.\nEndpoint: " + endPoint + "\n" + ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
```

I am not really sure why it coming up with that error, from the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol

it should come back with a 200 ok message, but I don't.
According to google api reference the problem is:

The request does not include the video content.

Now I assume that means the actual video because I have already passed the json, but I am unsure how (or even if) you can post the video at the same time as the json.

Please help me, this is driving me nuts :)

Cheers

cheers,
/r3plica

Answer (score 1):

You're leaving a few things out of your example (such as what `api.ApiUrl` is set to), but you're making a mistake if you're just trying to send a PUT request to `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos` whose body consists entirely of the video bytes.

If you want to implement your own upload code rather than using [the client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/), I'd strongly suggest that you [follow the steps outlined in this HTTP protocol-level guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol) to resumable uploads. It lists the correct URLs that you should be sending your requests to, as well as the relevant headers and request bodies to use.

The alternatively would be to construct a multipart MIME request body and send that to the correct URL, but resumable uploads is more robust and probably easier to implement by hand. (And I'm not aware of any protocol-level guide to multipart MIME uploads.)

Comment: yeah, this is probably what my issue is. I have updated my question now

Comment: You're not actually following the guide (you're using the wrong URL, for one thing). Implementing this by hand is difficult, and you have to be really, really careful about all the details if you want to do it. I'd really recommend that you just use the client library and follow the example at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_video

Comment: I can't use the client library. I know I am nearly there now, so just the final hurdle and I will be happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but in your If statement you have an or statement there perhaps that needs to be surrounded by parentheses , (size && mime ) || octet       or      size && (mime || octet).  I think logic is failing there somehow.  As it stands now I bet octets that are over the size limit are what causes your problems. The way your logic reads is if size and mime are ok then go OR if octet stream ok , and your size check never happens. I imagine you want this for your if statement.

```
if (maxSize > asset.FileSize && (asset.MimeType.ToLower().StartsWith("video/") || asset.MimeType.ToLower().Equals("application/octet-stream")))
```

Comment: no mate, the if statement is fine. It gets past that no problem, it is at the request.GetResponse() that the error is thrown :)

Comment: Ehh are you positive, that response is returned from the server saying that your request Entity is to large so what you are sending is to large. Yes its going to get through your If statement but that's the issue you don't want it to if the size is to large. Try putting an else on your if statement and test with an octet that's larger than 64gigs, if you output something in the else statement then yes your if statement is fine, if not and you get request is to large then your if statement isn't catching to large assets that are of octet-stream mime type.

Comment: Is this happening for all Filesizes? or just an occurance once in a while.

Comment: for all files and the test file is only 30 meg

Comment: I see, as far as the if statement concerns I still think you will have issues with larger than 64 gig octet-stream mime types sneaking through your logic.  As far as the actual uploading just looking at some google Developers guide you might try some of these steps to help get you going.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Uploading_Videos